# gnuplot date output in X doesn't display right

Tags: gnuplot

Im parsing linux sar output and i have dat file which looks like this :

```
07:09:49      CPU      %usr     %nice      %sys   %iowait    %steal      %irq     %soft    %guest     %idle
07:09:51      all      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00    100.00
07:09:53      all     11.82      0.00      0.13      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00     88.05
07:09:55      all     53.99      0.00      0.63      0.00      0.13      0.00      0.13      0.00     45.12
07:09:57      all     55.18      0.00      0.25      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00     44.57
07:09:59      all     66.58      0.00      0.51      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.13      0.00     32.78
07:10:01      all     71.90      0.00      0.63      0.13      0.00      0.00      0.13      0.00     27.22
07:10:03      all     70.24      0.00      0.63      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.13      0.00     29.00
07:10:05      all     55.39      0.00      0.63      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.13      0.00     43.85
07:10:07      all     72.90      0.00      0.38      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00     26.73
07:10:09      all     60.96      0.00      0.38      0.00      0.13      0.00      0.13      0.00     38.40
07:10:11      all     76.60      0.00      0.63      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.13      0.00     22.65
07:10:13      all     53.87      0.00      0.76      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.13      0.00     45.25
07:10:15      all     46.73      0.00      0.63      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00     52.64
07:10:17      all     56.37      0.00      0.50      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.13      0.00     43.00
07:10:19      all     58.15      0.00      0.63      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.13      0.00     41.09
07:10:21      all     61.26      0.00      0.75      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.13      0.00     37.86
07:10:23      all     51.50      0.00      0.75      0.12      0.12      0.00      0.25      0.00     47.2


set title ' CPU usage'
set xdata time
set timefmt '%H:%M:%S'
set xlabel 'time'
set ylabel 'CPU Usage'
set style data lines
plot 'filename.dat'  using 1:3 title '0.6'
pause -1
```

the out put in the X data is not related to the time presented in the file 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the formatting of the tic labels:

```
set format x '%H:%M:%S'
```

Comment: I changed it to :
set title ' CPU usage'
set xdata time
set format x '%H:%M:%S'
set xlabel 'time'
set ylabel 'CPU Usage'
set style data lines
plot 'filename.dat'  using 1:3 title '0.6'

and it give me error:
"myscript.plg", line 8: warning: Skipping data file with no valid points

plot filename  using 1:3 title '0.6'
                                    ^
"myscript.plg", line 8: x range is invalid

Comment: @user63898 You must have both lines `set timefmt '%H:%M:%S'` and `set format x '%H:%M:%S'`.